# Practicing Java servlets, MySQL and JSON - follow-up

Tags: java, mysql, json, controller, servlets

(See the [previous iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172476/practicing-java-servlets-mysql-and-json).)

## What's new

I have incorporated all the points of [Dmytro Maslenko](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/143775/dmytro-maslenko)'s answer. My code seems a little bit tidier.

## Code

**AddPersonController.java**

```
package net.coderodde.web.db.fun.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import net.coderodde.web.db.fun.model.FunnyPerson;

/**
 * This controller is responsible for creating new persons.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Aug 8, 2017)
 */
@WebServlet(name = "AddPersonController", urlPatterns = {"/add_person"})
public class AddPersonController extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request  the servlet request.
     * @param response the servlet response.
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs.
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("Please use the POST method!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request  the servlet request.
     * @param response the servlet response.
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs.
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            String firstName = request.getParameter("first_name");
            String lastName = request.getParameter("last_name");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");

            if (firstName.isEmpty()) {
                out.println("The first name is empty.");
                return;
            }

            if (lastName.isEmpty()) {
                out.println("The last name is empty.");
                return;
            }

            if (email.isEmpty()) {
                out.println("The email is empty.");
                return;
            }

            FunnyPerson person = new FunnyPerson();
            person.setFirstName(firstName);
            person.setLastName(lastName);
            person.setEmail(email);

            try {
                DataAccessObject.instance().addPerson(person);
                out.println("Person " + person + " created!");
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                out.println("Error: " + ex.getCause().getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "This servlet adds new persons to the database.";
    }
}
```

**CreateDatabaseController.java**

```
package net.coderodde.web.db.fun.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * This controller creates the database if it is not yet created.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Aug 8, 2017)
 */
@WebServlet(name = "CreateDatabaseController", urlPatterns = {"/create"})
public class CreateDatabaseController extends HttpServlet {


    /**
     * If not yet created, this request creates the database and the table.
     *
     * @param request  the servlet request.
     * @param response the servlet response.
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs.
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            try {
                DataAccessObject.instance().createDatabase();
                out.println("Database created!");
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                out.println("Error: " + ex.getCause().getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request  the servlet request.
     * @param response the servlet response.
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs.
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request  the servlet request.
     * @param response the servlet response.
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs.
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description.
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Creates the database and the table.";
    }
}
```

**DataAccessObject.java**

```
package net.coderodde.web.db.fun.controllers;

import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import net.coderodde.web.db.fun.model.FunnyPerson;

public final class DataAccessObject {

    /**
     * For validating the email addresses.
     */
    public static final Pattern VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX = 
    Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$",
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    /**
     * The SQL command for inserting a person.
     */
    private static final String INSERT_PERSON_SQL = 
            "INSERT INTO funny_persons (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES " +
            "(?, ?, ?);";

    /**
     * Creates a new database if not already created.
     */
    private static final String CREATE_DATABASE_SQL = 
            "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS funny_db;";

    /**
     * Switches to 'funny_db'.
     */
    private static final String USE_DATABASE_SQL = "USE funny_db";

    /**
     * Creates the table if not already created.
     */
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SQL =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS funny_persons (\n" +
                "id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
                "first_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,\n" +
                "last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,\n" +
                "email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,\n" +
                "created TIMESTAMP);";

    /**
     * The SQL for selecting a user given his/her ID.
     */
    private static final String GET_USER_BY_ID_SQL = 
            "SELECT * FROM funny_persons WHERE id = ?;";

    private final MysqlDataSource mysqlDataSource;

    private DataAccessObject(MysqlDataSource mysqlDataSource) {
        this.mysqlDataSource = Objects.requireNonNull(
                mysqlDataSource, 
                "The MysqlDataSource is null.");
    }

    private static final DataAccessObject INSTANCE;

    static {
        MysqlDataSource mysqlDataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        mysqlDataSource.setUser("root");
        mysqlDataSource.setPassword("your_password");
        mysqlDataSource.setURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/funny_db");
        INSTANCE = new DataAccessObject(mysqlDataSource);
    }

    public static DataAccessObject instance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a person to the database.
     * 
     * @param person the person to add.
     */
    public void addPerson(FunnyPerson person) {
        checkPerson(person);

        try (Connection connection = mysqlDataSource.getConnection()) {
            try (PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_PERSON_SQL)) {
                statement.setString(1, person.getFirstName().trim());
                statement.setString(2, person.getLastName().trim());
                statement.setString(3, person.getEmail().trim());
                statement.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates the empty database and the table.
     */
    public void createDatabase() {
        try (Connection connection = mysqlDataSource.getConnection()) {
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                statement.executeUpdate(CREATE_DATABASE_SQL);
                statement.executeUpdate(USE_DATABASE_SQL);
                statement.executeUpdate(CREATE_TABLE_SQL);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets a user by his/her ID.
     * 
     * @param id the ID of the user.
     * @return a {@code FunnyPerson} object or {@code null} if there is not such
     *         user.
     */
    public FunnyPerson getUserById(int id) {
        try (Connection connection = mysqlDataSource.getConnection()) {
            try (PreparedStatement statement = 
                    connection.prepareStatement(GET_USER_BY_ID_SQL)) {
                statement.setInt(1, id);

                try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                    if (!resultSet.next()) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    FunnyPerson person = new FunnyPerson();

                    person.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                    person.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
                    person.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
                    person.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
                    person.setCreated(resultSet.getDate("created"));

                    return person;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    private void checkPerson(FunnyPerson person) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(person, "The person is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(person.getFirstName(), 
                               "The first name is null.");

        Objects.requireNonNull(person.getLastName(), "The last name is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(person.getEmail(), "The email is null.");

        if (person.getFirstName().trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The first name is empty.");
        }

        if (person.getLastName().trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The last name is empty.");
        }

        if (!validate(person.getEmail().trim())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid email address.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks the email address.
     * 
     * @param email the email address to validate.
     * @return {@code true} if {@code email} is a valid email address.
     */
    private static boolean validate(String email ) {
        Matcher matcher = VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX .matcher(email );
        return matcher.find();
    }
}
```

**ShowPersonController.java**

```
package net.coderodde.web.db.fun.controllers;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import net.coderodde.web.db.fun.model.FunnyPerson;

/**
 * This controller is responsible for viewing persons.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Aug 8, 2017)
 */
@WebServlet(name = "ShowPersonController", urlPatterns = {"/show/*"})
public class ShowPersonController extends HttpServlet {


    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request  the servlet request.
     * @param response the servlet response.
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs.
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            String path = request.getPathInfo();

            if (path.startsWith("/")) {
                path = path.substring(1);
            }

            String[] tokens = path.split("/");

            if (tokens.length == 0) {
                out.println("Error: At least the user ID is required.");
                return;
            }

            String idString = tokens[0];
            int id = -1;

            try {
                id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                out.println("Error: " + idString + " is not an integer.");
                return;
            }

            FunnyPerson person = DataAccessObject.instance().getUserById(id);

            if (person == null) {
                out.println("Error: no person with ID = " + id + ".");
                return;
            }

            String matchFirstName = null;

            if (tokens.length == 2) {
                matchFirstName = tokens[1];
            }

            if (!person.getFirstName().equals(matchFirstName)) {
                response.sendRedirect("/DBWebFun/show/" + id + "/" + 
                                      person.getFirstName());
                return;
            }

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            out.println(gson.toJson(person));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Shows the user info via ID/first_name";
    }
}
```

The entire Maven project is [here](https://github.com/coderodde/DBWebFun).

## Critique request

Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

### AddPersonController

- content type value should be extracted into a constant or taken from an existing list in a related lib (but I'm not sure there is such list of constants in Servlet API).
- `doGet` outputs `Please use the POST method!` with successful response code. It looks much more like `405 Method not allowed` and would better return this response code.
- For error output, the response code should be set correctly. Currently, even in case of errors, all requests will look like `200 OK`.
- `doPost` method is too long. It does three things: extraction and validation of the args; 2) initialization of `person`; 3) saving the person. This method should be split.
- avoid `try` blocks nesting.
- there are cases of repetitive output of error messages across different classes. It would be a good idea to extract `out.println("Error: " + ex.getCause().getMessage())` into a shortcut method.

### CreateDatabaseController

- both `doPost` and `doGet` are bad choice for the action to create a database. Objects creation corresponds to `POST` verb, so `doGet` should be removed.

### ShowPersonController

- `processRequest` is just too long, please split it in logical parts.
- the case is inverse here for `doGet` and `doPost`: this controller is used to show persons information, not to create entries. This is the verb `GET`. So `doPost` is to remove.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Antot's answer. Some more from my side.

**`checkPerson` method:**

```
private void checkPerson(FunnyPerson person) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(person, "The person is null.");
    Objects.requireNonNull(person.getFirstName(), 
                           "The first name is null.");

    Objects.requireNonNull(person.getLastName(), "The last name is null.");
    Objects.requireNonNull(person.getEmail(), "The email is null.");

    if (person.getFirstName().trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The first name is empty.");
    }

    if (person.getLastName().trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The last name is empty.");
    }

    if (!validate(person.getEmail().trim())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid email address.");
    }
}
```

can be simplified by using Apache commons lang [Validate](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html):

```
private void checkPerson(FunnyPerson person) {
    Validate.notNull(person, "The person is null.");
    Validate.notBlank(person.getFirstName(), "The first name is null or blank.");
    Validate.notBlank(person.getLastName(), "The last name is null or blank.");
    Validate.notBlank(person.getEmail(), "The email is null or blank.");
}
```

---

**In `processRequest()`** you have an the end:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
out.println(gson.toJson(person));
```

Move up this logging and put right after getting of person.

---

**About logging.** Avoid `println`, try to reuse at least embedded [Java logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html) but better look at third party loggers like `slf4j`, `logback`, etc.

Comment: instead of relying on Apache Commons I'd recommend to rely on JPA and related APis, which would also vastly clean up the DAOs by abstracting the SQL statements away